# Error: MySQLSyntaxErrorException - select command denied to user

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-security

I'm connecting to a distant MySQL database from my web application I'm using hibernate and spring frameworks

when I try to get element from the database, it doesn't work due to lack of privilege.

```
 public Medecin getMedecinByLoginPassword(String login, String password) {
    System.out.println(login);
    System.out.println(password);
    List list;
    list = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
       .createQuery("from Medecin where login= :login and password= :password")
       .setString("login", login).setString("password", password).list();
    return (Medecin) list.get(0);
}
```

only Native sql works to get data from the distant database any thing else i get this error

**Error**

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: SELECT command denied to user 'tunisie_tunisie'@'196.203.218.102' for table 'medecin'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1885)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
... 83 more
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: SELECT command denied to user 'tunisie_tunisie'@'196.203.218.102' for table 'medecin'
```

This states clearly that the database you are trying to connect with the username `tunisie_tunisie` at host ip `196.203.218.102` is not authorized to use this table. Check that you have correct permissions  to access this database.

Comment: I have discussed that with the web host manager but he affirmed that the problem is in my code i can establish a connexion with the database from other java application and get data but from this application it doesn't work

Comment: Make sure if you are able to connect using the db details. You can use this code to test [link](http://www.ekiras.com/2014/09/create-mysql-database-jdbc-connection-in-java.html). If you are able to make connection to the db by this code then, you need to check your code. BUt first check if you are able to connect the db with this code.

Comment: The connection is successfully established 
I think it's a problem of privilege due to spring-security framework

Answer (score 0):

Too late to answer but this is because of the incorrect schema/table:

```
.createQuery("from Medecin where login= :login and password= :password")
```

here M is capital, but when you are getting the error:

```
SELECT command denied to user 'tunisie_tunisie'@'196.203.218.102' for table 'medecin'
```

here is in small letters, MySQL is case sensitive make sure to check that twice.